# Does device driver works without calling probe function

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver

Recently I was Trying to work with Qualcomm platform device. I was looking at Flow of touchscreen hbtp_input device driver, the driver is getting registered and calling init function but it doesn't call probe function.Does drivers work without probe functions?

Comment: Apparently this one does (by calling `misc_register` to register a single miscellaneous device), but the probe sets up some stuff to do with the device. The driver only seems to be in various Android kernel trees, not the mainline Linux kernel trees.

Comment: @Ian Abbott thank you Ian... I am new to kernel and device drivers. I am assuming you worked on this driver if so than,Can you please ellobrate how this hbtp touch screen driver works like what happens when we touch the screen, how it gets interrupted.

Comment: Sorry, I've never worked on the driver in question.